# I am not able to create a Liferay Plugin Project

Tags: liferay, portlet

```
[Console output redirected to                file:C:\Rahul13615\liferay\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\com.liferay.ide.    sdk.core\sdk.log]
Buildfile: C:\Rahul13615\liferay\plugins\portlets\build.xml
  [get] Getting: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-    2.3.0.jar
  [get] To: C:\Rahul13615\liferay\plugins\.ivy\ivy-2.3.0.jar
  [get] Error getting    http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar to    C:\Rahul13615\liferay\plugins\.ivy\ivy-2.3.0.jar

BUILD FAILED
C:\Rahul13615\liferay\plugins\portlets\build.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Rahul13615\liferay\plugins\build-common-plugins.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Rahul13615\liferay\plugins\build-common.xml:47: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Rahul13615\liferay\plugins\build-common-ivy.xml:17: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Total time: 1 minute 27 seconds
```

I try to create a new project and this happens. I tried changing the jre version from 1.8 to 1.7, it didnt work..Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ivy.jar.url=https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/liferay-public-snapshots/com/liferay/org.apache.ivy/2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT/org.apache.ivy-2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

instead your current `ivy.jar.url=...`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I changed the ivy.jar.url to the above mentioned url and now it came up with a new error as follows:

Comment: Following is the error: 
Buildfile: C:\Rahul13615\liferay\plugins\portlets\build.xml
      [get] Getting: https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/liferay-public-snapshots/com/liferay/org.apache.ivy/2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT/org.apache.ivy-2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT.jar
      [get] To: C:\Rahul13615\liferay\plugins\.ivy\org.apache.ivy-2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.